# Popup window (in WPF UIAccess application) not rendered in Windows 10

Tags: wpf, popup, windows-10, mahapps.metro

An application that I've written (https://github.com/JuliusSweetland/OptiKey) requests UIAccess (to be able to be rendered above everything) and has a modal popup window styled using MahApps.Metro. When run on Windows 8/8.1 everything is fine, but on Windows 10 the popup window does not display (is not rendered anywhere), but is visible in the taskbar. Hovering over the thumbnail displays the preview, but the window can never be made visible.

I have narrowed the problem down to Windows 10 and whether the **UIAccess="true"** setting in the manifest is true/false (it is fine if set to false).

I initially thought the problem was linked to the .Net 2.0.0.0 runtime not being present on a default install of Windows 10, as the problem went away when I installed Snoop (which I think installed .Net 3.5 and so the 2.0.0.0 runtime), but to prove the fix I uninstalled .Net 3.5, which brought back the issue with the child window, and then re-installed .Net 3.5, which did NOT resolve the issue again.

I have tried the following:

1. Running application as admin = no fix
2. Updating all graphics drivers = no fix
3. Checking the event logs = nothing
4. Converting my child (popup) window to be non-modal = no fix
5. Converting my child (popup) window to be a standard Window class, rather than a MetroWindow (MahApps) = no fix
6. 4 & 5 = no fix
7. Installing .Net 3.5 = no fix

The only thing that works is setting UIAccess="false", but I need it to be true.

N.B. UIAccess is working correctly on Windows 8.1, and I have fulfilled the requirements (adding UIAccess="true" to the manifest, signing the assembly, and running from a protected directory "Program Files")

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Can you post the relevant XAML? I'm using MahApps on Windows 10 and had no problems so far. BTW congratulations on your app, everyone loves it and you're a hero.

Comment: This is the window: https://github.com/JuliusSweetland/OptiKey/blob/master/src/UI/Windows/ManagementWindow.xaml

Comment: Code behind: https://github.com/JuliusSweetland/OptiKey/blob/master/src/UI/Windows/ManagementWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: Window hotkey set up here: https://github.com/JuliusSweetland/OptiKey/blob/master/src/UI/Windows/MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: Trigger action to launch management window: https://github.com/JuliusSweetland/OptiKey/blob/master/src/UI/TriggerActions/OpenManagementWindowAction.cs

Comment: hmmm... looks like a regular `MetroWindow`, should work just fine. Do you happen to have a secondary monitor? We've had a similar issue with custom-styled WPF windows (from a third party control vendor) where a Window won't be displayed if its default position was on a secondary screen, unless I forced it to restore, then maximize via code. btw, does the window appear if you right click -> restore in the task bar?

Comment: run https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy and look if you reference a .net 2.0/3.5 library

Comment: No secondary monitor and it does not work if I attempt to minimise/restore again. It actually behaves as if the UI thread is locked - animations on the main window (which spawns the management console window) are frozen and Snoop cannot be used when injected into OptiKey either. I've added "EDIT 2" as I think the issue may be something to do with UIAccess and child modal windows. I will investigate assembly references when I get home also - thank you.

Comment: Changing UIAccess="true" to UIAccess="false" in the manifest fixes this problem, but I don't know why. I also need UIAccess, so I'm still stuck. (Making the popup window non-modal did not help, and neither did ensuring that runtime 2.0.0.0 is installed, by installing .Net 3.5).

Comment: I also tried changing the window type to be a normal Window (not a MetroWindow), which did nothing. It's something to do with the UIAccess flag. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - as part of launching the child window I was setting the parent window's TopMost property to false (and then setting it back to its original value when the child window closed). Something about setting parentWindow.TopMost=false was causing the invisible child window problem. I removed the relevant lines (in this commit: https://github.com/JuliusSweetland/OptiKey/commit/e9031119a726518f54da94c64faceeee991b3747) and everything works again.